# Why text elements are not shown in stand-alone SVG

Tags: svg

Why does the browser show if this is embedded in html as SVG element, but not if the SVG is stored separately. Lines are shown in both cases:

`<svg version ="1.1" class="scaling-svg" viewbox="0 0 840 840" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" > <TEXT xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="420" y="20" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" fill="#646464">Text</TEXT>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive and the correct element name is text and not TEXT.

HTML however is not case sensitive so if you embed SVG in HTML it's HTML rules for parsing markup and that means it auto converts TEXT to the correct form.